# Can any reasonable CPU implementation give foo = 2 in this case?

Tags: assembly, concurrency, operating-system, race-condition

Reading a very interesting [blog post](http://danluu.com/new-cpu-features/) by Dan Luu about advances in x86 architecture over the past few decades, he says:

> If we set `_foo` to 0 and have two threads that both execute `incl (_foo)` 10000 times each, incrementing the same location with a single instruction 20000 times, is guaranteed not to exceed 20000, but it could (theoretically) be as low as 2. If it’s not obvious why the theoretical minimum is 2 and not 10000, figuring that out is a good exercise.

where `_foo` is some memory address.

Obviously this is because (as he says farther down) `incl` is implemented as a load followed by an add followed by a store. So if you "desugar" it into:

```
mov reg, _foo ;; #1
inc reg       ;; #2
mov _foo, reg ;; #3
```

Then the following ordering of u-ops results in `_foo = 2`:

```
Thread A executes #1, #2
Thread B executes #1, #2
Thread A executes #3
Thread B executes #3
Thread A executes #1, #2.... etc
```

(I may be muddling the details of assembler here a little bit, but as far as I know this is a reasonably accurate description of the case where `_foo = 2`.)

What I wonder about is his next "exercise:"

> [M]y bonus exercise for you is, can any reasonable CPU implementation get that result, or is that some silly thing the spec allows that will never happen? There isn’t enough information in this post to answer the bonus question...

Can it? My instinct is no because I believe that when A executes `#3`, then either:

- A and B are on the same CPU. B won't get to run until A's timeslice is up, and there's no way that it will take a whole timeslice to execute a single instruction, so eventually someone is going to write out a value > 2, or
- A and B are on different CPUs. A's write causes B's cache to become invalidated and A gets to continue executing, writing out a value > 2.

But I'm not positive if every store causes every other cache to get invalidated, or if A is able to continue running during that time, and I'm not sure if OS-level things like timeslices should apply to  reasoning about CPUs.

Comment: Your question is muddled by "reasonable". What do you think a reasonable CPU is? For instance, is a CPU reasonable when it executes instructions out of order? Because most modern CPUs do that. Or is a CPU reasonable when different cores have different speeds or some cores are turned off? Because CPUs do that too.

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu The author of the blog does hardware design for MS and Google, so I would expect his definition of "reasonable" to pretty closely track what most modern CPUs do. It's also worth noting that I'm not looking for an answer that seems "reasonable" to me, I'm wondering what the original author's intent was, since he is an expert in the field.

Comment: Modern CPU's are not more reasonable. On the contrary they do all the crazy things nowadays that I mentioned above. He must have meant "bug-free" or something like that. (I thought it was you sorry).

Comment: The same CPU case is even less interesting than that. The INC instruction can't be interrupted in the middle so the result is guaranteed to be always 20,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr summary**: not possible on a single core with the one-instruction `inc [foo]`.  Maybe possible with each thread on its own core, but I think only with hyperthreading to create extra delays on stores by causing cache evictions between the load/inc and the store.

I think not even multi-socket cache coherency can be slow enough for B's final store to be delayed 50k cycles after B's final load, but hyperthreading might be able to queue multiple cache/TLB misses ahead of it.

---

In the single-core case: your assumption that *B won't get to run until A's timeslice is up* doesn't necessarily hold.  An interrupt (e.g. a timer interrupt or NIC) can come in at any point, suspending execution of a user-space thread at any instruction boundary.  Perhaps after the interrupt, a higher-priority process wakes up and is scheduled onto the CPU for a while, so there's no reason for the scheduler to prefer the thread that had already run for a fraction of a timeslice.

However, if we're just talking about the single-core case, and concurrency can only happen via context switches, `inc [mem]` is very different from `mov reg, [mem]` / `inc reg` / `mov [mem], reg`.  Regardless of how the CPU internals handle `inc [mem]`, **a context switch only saves/restores the *architectural* state**.  If the load and inc part had already internally completed, but not the store, the whole instruction couldn't have retired.  A context switch wouldn't save/restore that progress: the load and inc would have to be re-run when the thread started executing again and the the CPU saw the `inc [mem]` instruction again.

If the test had used separate load/inc/store instructions, even a single-core machine could in theory get `2` by the sequence Michael Burr points out:

```
A loads 0 from _foo
B loops 9999 times (finally storing _foo = 9999)
A stores _foo = 1  (end of first iteration)
B's final iteration loads 1 from _foo
A loops 9999 times (eventually storing _foo = 10000)
B's final iteration stores _foo = 2
```

This is possible, but would require several context switches triggered by interrupts arriving at extremely specific times.  It takes many cycles from an interrupt that causes the scheduler to preempt a thread to the point where the first instruction from a new thread actually runs.  There's probably enough time for another interrupt to arrive.  We're just interested in it being possible, not likely enough to be observable even after days of trials!

Again, with `inc [mem]`, this is *impossible* on a single core, because context switches can only happen after whole instructions.  The CPU's architectural state has either executed the `inc` or not.

---

In a **multicore** situation, with both threads running at the same time, things are entirely different.  Cache coherency operations can happen between the uops that a single instruction is decoded into.  So `inc [mem]` isn't a single operation in this context.

I'm not sure about this, but I think it might be possible even for a single-instruction `inc [foo]` loop to produce a final result of 2.  Interrupts / context switches can't account for delays between load and store, though, so we need to come up with other possible reasons.

- A loads 0 from `foo`
- B loops 9999 times (finally storing foo = 9999).  The cache line is now in the `E` state on B's CPU core
- A stores _foo = 1  (end of first iteration).  This could conceivably be delayed this long on a hyperthreaded CPU by the other logical thread saturating the store port with a big backlog of stores which miss in cache and/or TLB, and by the store being buffered for a while.  Possibly this can happen without hyperthreading with several cache-miss stores waiting to complete.  Remember that stores become globally visible in program order in x86's strong memory model, so a later store to a hot cache line still has to wait.  Having it complete just in time for B's last iteration is just a coincidence in timing, which is fine.
- B's final iteration loads 1 from foo.  (An interrupt or something could delay B's execution of the final iteration.  This doesn't require anything to happen between the load/inc/store uops of a single instruction, so I don't need to figure out if receiving a coherency message (from A) that invalidates the cache line will prevent store-forwarding from forwarding the 9999 value from the previous iteration's store to this iteration's load.  I'm not sure, but I think it could.)
- A loops 9999 times (eventually storing `_foo = 10000`)
- B's final iteration stores `_foo = 2`.  **Explaining how this store can be delayed until after A's loop completes seems like the biggest stretch**.  Hyperthreading could do it: the other logical core could evict the TLB entry for `_foo`, and maybe also evict the L1 D$ line containing the value.  This eviction could happen between the load and the store uops for the final `inc` instruction.  I'm not sure how long it can take for the coherency protocol to obtain write access to a cache line that's currently owned by another core.  I'm sure it's usually far less than 50k cycles, actually less than a main memory access on CPUs with large include last-level caches that act as a backstop for coherency traffic (e.g. Intel's Nehalem and later designs).  Very-many-core systems with multiple sockets are potentially slow, but I think they still use a ring bus for coherency traffic.

  I'm not sure it's plausible for B's final store to be delayed 50k cycles without hyperthreading to pile up some store-port contention and cause cache evictions.  The load (which has to see A's store of 1, but not any of A's other stores) can't get too far ahead of the store in the OOO scheduler, since it still has to come after the store from the penultimate iteration.  (A core must maintain in-order semantics within a single execution context.)

Since there's only a single memory location that's read and then written in both threads, there isn't any reordering of stores and loads.  A load will always see previous stores from the same thread, so it can't become globally visible until after a store to the same location.

On x86, only [StoreLoad reordering](http://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/) is possible, but in this case the only thing that matters is that the out-of-order machinery can delay the store for a long time, even without reordering it relative to any loads.

---

---

The original blog post you're referring to looks good in general, but I did notice at least one mistake.  There are a lot of good links in there.

> it turns out that on modern x86 CPUs, using locking to implement
>   concurrency primitives is [often cheaper than using memory
>   barriers](https://blogs.oracle.com/dave/resource/NHM-Pipeline-Blog-V2.txt)

That link just shows that using `lock add [mem], 0` *as a barrier* is cheaper on Nehalem, and esp. that it interleaves better with other instructions.  It has nothing to say about using locking vs. lockless algorithms that depend on barriers.  If you want to atomically increment a memory location, then the simplest choice by far is a `lock`ed instruction.  Using just `MFENCE` would require some kind of separate lock implemented without atomic RMW operations, if that's possible.

Clearly he wanted to introduce the topic of `lock inc [mem]` vs. `inc [mem]`, and just wasn't careful about the wording.  In most cases his generalizations work better.

---

The example code is also weird, and compiling with `-O0` [makes quite nasty code](http://goo.gl/IWk5sk) as always.  I fixed the inline asm to ask the compiler for a memory operand, rather than manually writing `incl (reg)`, so with optimization on, it produces `incl counter(%rip)` instead of loading the pointer into a register.  More importantly, `-O3` also avoids keeping the loop counter in memory, even with the original source.  `-O3` on the original source still appears to produce correct code, even though it doesn't tell the compiler that it writes to memory.

Anyway, flawed as the experiment is, I think the experiment is still valid, and it's unlikely that the huge loop overhead of compiling with `-O0` added an artificial limit to the range the final counter could end up with.

---

Dan Luu's example asm syntax is a weird mix of Intel and AT&T syntax: `mov [_foo], %eax` is a load.  It should be written `mov eax, [_foo]`, or `mov _foo, %eax`, or maybe `mov (_foo), %eax` if you're trying to make it clear that it's a load rather than a mov-immediate.  Anyway, I think it would be  confusing if I didn't already know what he meant and was trying to demonstrate.

---

Comment: Fantastic, this is what I was hoping for. I suspect the answer he expected was "no," then, and your commentary on the article is helpful, too. Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickCollins: There might be something I'm missing.  I'd be interested to see Dan Luu's official answer, if he's ever posted one.  I suspect you're right that he's expecting the "no" answer, esp. since I'm not even sure that hyperthreading can cause a 50k cycle delay between the load and store from a single `inc`.  Oh hmm, I wonder if a transition between CPU frequencies (e.g. ramping up from 1.6GHz to 3.3GHz) might cause a big delay without flushing the OOO pipeline.  It's certainly plausible, since it has to wait for the new supply voltage to settle before starting the clock again.

Answer (score 4):

```
A executes #1, #2
B executes #1, #2, #3 9999 times  (_foo == 9999)
A executes #3    (_foo == 1)
B executes #1, #2   (part of iteration 10000, and reg == 2)
A executes #1, #2, #3 9999 times  (completing its total of 10000 iterations)
B executes #3  (writing 2 to _foo)
```

Comment: This isn't an execution that I had thought of, but I'm not so sure it answers the "any reasonable CPU implementation" aspect of the question. Is there any kind of relevant spec, standard, or other "ground truth" that speaks towards this case?

Comment: In particular, I wonder if "B executes #1, #2, #3, A executes #3; B executes #1, #2..." isn't effectively impossible because A's write invalidates B's cache and so prevents B from executing anything else for at least a few dozen cycles. That's the sort of thing where I would say a "reasonable implementation" might differ from the spec, because the spec won't take into account how long a cache invalidation will take.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: If this was a sequence of 3 x86 instructions doing load / inc reg / store, it would be easy to see how this could happen: an interrupt can come in at any time, even if a thread has just started executing.  Even in a single-core system, context switches could produce this.  However, since this is `inc [mem]`, the instruction either retires or not, even though it decodes to 3 uops (Intel SnB-family).  An interrupt can't suspend/resume execution with the load done but not the store.  However, x86 allows StoreLoad reordering (i.e. you get stale prefetched data).

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't quite follow what you're saying about StoreLoad reordering --- does it prevent the example in this post, or allow it? I'm really interested in an answer to this that speaks to the spec or the memory model of real processors and it sounds like you can give an answer along those lines.

Comment: See http://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/.  You don't *always* get stale data from loads, so it's possible for A to clobber `_foo` from 9999 back to 1 by doing the load early, but also have B see A's store of 1 when it's doing the load for its last iteration.  An interrupt could explanain for `1` becoming globally visible, rather than being overwritten in the L1 cache line before it could be seen by other CPUs.

Comment: However, I think a read request from another core could also change the cache line from M (modified) to S (shared) if it came in when the first iteration's `inc` had retired, but not the 2nd iteration's.  I'm not sure how store-forwarding interacts with cache state, but non-retired instructions almost certainly can't make their results visible to other CPUs, in case they turn out not to retire at all (e.g. an exception or branch mispredict is detected in an earlier instruction.)

Comment: @PatrickCollins: I might turn this into an answer tomorrow, after I have another think about it to see if I'm right.  Go read Jeff Preshing's blog, not just that article.  He has some great stuff.  Also, sorry to confuse you with the half-done comment that didn't fit into a single 600char chunk

Comment: @PeterCordes I'll take a look, thanks for the link. I'd love to see a more crunchy answer for this in terms of how real CPUs concretely work, I hope you come back to flesh it out.