# Does compare_exchange based loop benefit from pause?

Tags: c++, c++11, x86, atomic, compare-and-swap

In a CAS based loop, for example the one below, is the use of pause beneficial on x86?

```
void atomicLeftShift(atomic<int>& var, int shiftBy)
{
    While(true) {
        int oldVal = var;
        int newVal = oldVal << shiftBy;
         if(var.compare_exchange_weak(oldVal, newVal));
             break;
        else
            _mm_pause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524249), I'm going to say yes.

Comment: It should not matter because a failing CAS should be rare,. If this is going to make a difference, you might have too much contention

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, I don't think so.  This isn't a spin-wait.**  It's not waiting for another thread to store a `0` or something.  It *does* make sense to try again right away after `lock cmpxchg` fails, rather than sleep ~100 cycles (on Skylake and later) or ~5 cycles (on earlier Intel CPUs).

For `lock cmpxchg` to complete at all (success or fail) means that the cache line is now in Modified (or maybe just Exclusive?) state on *this* core, so *right now* is the perfect time to try again.

**Real use cases for lockless atomics are usually *not* extremely heavily contended, or else you should normally use a fallback to an OS-assisted sleep/wake.**

(But if there is contention, there is hardware arbitration for `lock`ed instructions; in a highly contended case I don't know if it's likely for a core to get to execute a 2nd `lock`ed instruction before losing the cache line again.  But hopefully yes.)

`lock cmpxchg` can't fail spuriously, so actual livelock is impossible: at least one core will make progress by having its CAS succeed in an algorithm like this, for a round of every core having a go.  On a LL/SC architecture, `compare_exchange_weak` can fail spuriously, so portability to non-x86 might need to care about livelock, depending on implementation details, but I think even so it's unlikely.  (And of course `_mm_pause` specifically is x86 only.)

---

Another reason for using `pause` is to avoid a memory-order mis-speculation when leaving a spin-wait loop that spins read-only waiting to see the lock unlocked before trying to atomically claim it.  (This is better than spinning on `xchg` or `lock cmpxchg` and having all waiting threads hammering on the cache line.)

But that's again not an issue here because the retry loop already includes `lock cmpxchg` which is a full barrier as well as atomic RMW, so I think that avoids memory-order mis-speculation.

---

**Especially if you write the loop efficiently / correctly to use the load result of cmpxchg failure when retrying, removing the pure load of `var` from the loop**.

This is the canonical way to construct an arbitrary atomic operation out of a CAS primitive.  `compare_exchange_weak` updates its first arg if the compare fails, so you don't need another load inside the loop.

```
#include <atomic>

int atomicLeftShift(std::atomic<int>& var, int shiftBy)
{
    int expected = var.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    int desired;
    do {
        desired = expected << shiftBy;
    } while( !var.compare_exchange_weak(expected, desired) );  // seq_cst
    return desired;
}
```

compiles with [clang7.0 -O3 for x86-64](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A%0Aint+atomicLeftShift(std::atomic%3Cint%3E%26+var,+int+shiftBy)%0A%7B%0A++++int+expected+%3D+var.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)%3B%0A++++int+desired%3B%0A++++do+%7B%0A++++++++desired+%3D+expected+%3C%3C+shiftBy%3B%0A++++%7D+while(+!!var.compare_exchange_weak(expected,+desired)+)%3B++//+seq_cst%0A++++return+desired%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:30.513668137019106,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:67.60000000000001,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+7.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:32.4,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:69.4863318629809,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) to this asm, on the Godbolt compiler explorer:

```
atomicLeftShift(std::atomic<int>&, int):      
    mov     ecx, esi
    mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]        # pure load outside the loop

.LBB0_1:                              # do {
    mov     edx, eax
    shl     edx, cl                     # desired = expected << count
    lock            cmpxchg dword ptr [rdi], edx   # eax = implicit expected, updated on failure
    jne     .LBB0_1                   # } while(!CAS)
    mov     eax, edx                  # return value
    ret
```

The only memory access in the retry-loop is `lock cmpxchg`, which can't suffer from memory-order mis-speculation.  There's no need for `pause` for that reason.

---

There's no need for `pause` for simple backoff delay either, unless you have lots of contention and want to let one thread do multiple things in a row to the same shared variable to increase throughput.  i.e. to have other threads back off in the rare case where `cmpxchg` fails.

This *only* makes sense if it's normal for one thread to do multiple atomic operations in a row on the same variable (or one in the same cache line if you have false-sharing problems), instead of putting more operations into one CAS-retry.

This is probably rare in real code, but common in a synthetic microbenchmark where you let multiple threads hammer away on a shared variable repeatedly with no other work in between.

Comment: Good tip to move the load outside the loop!

Comment: Just found out godbolt can also do IACA-like assembly analysis via llvm-mca: https://godbolt.org/z/MPOE_H

Comment: Or with comparison: https://godbolt.org/z/5c6S5x. What do you think about its output?

Comment: @Trass3r: neat, I didn't know llvm had that.  Will be interesting to look at for a loop where IACA would be useful, unlike this one.  IACA / LLVM-MCA are useful when a loop is bottlenecked on microarchitectural things inside the core running it, not on memory.  The version with `pause` has a taken branch on the fast path, and like I said in the answer has basically no advantage except in a weird case where you want to let another thread keep messing with a cache line if your CAS failed, even though CAS executing at all means you now have the cache line in Exclusive state (or maybe Modified).

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure how I managed to miss it: https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2018-March/121490.html

Comment: The first paragraph is key